# Unconditional Generative Adverserial Networks on MNIST dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

I am training unconditional GANs on MNIST dataset using tfgan library and tfgan estimators. Things are working fine and images are being generated, [see](https://github.com/shubham2206/GANS_unconditional_MNIST/blob/master/MNIST_unconditional_tflayers.ipynb) . The helper functions for the generator and discriminator model functions are written using `tf.layers`. But when I am changing the helper functions only and writing them using `tf.keras` the same exact code is not working and no images are being generated, [see](https://github.com/shubham2206/GANS_unconditional_MNIST/blob/master/MNIST_unconditional_tfkeras.ipynb). Can anyone help me out with this? The only difference between the two scripts is change in helper functions from using `tf.layers` to using `tf.keras`.
Helper functions using tf.layers:

```
def _dense(inputs, units, l2_weight):
  return tf.layers.dense(
      inputs, units, None,
      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform,
      kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight),
      bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight))

def _batch_norm(inputs, is_training):
  return tf.layers.batch_normalization(
      inputs, momentum=0.999, epsilon=0.001, training=is_training)

def _deconv2d(inputs, filters, kernel_size, stride, l2_weight):
  return tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(
      inputs, filters, [kernel_size, kernel_size], strides=[stride, stride], 
      activation=tf.nn.relu, padding='same',
      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform,
      kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight),
      bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight))

def _conv2d(inputs, filters, kernel_size, stride, l2_weight):
  return tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs, filters, [kernel_size, kernel_size], strides=[stride, stride], 
      activation=None, padding='same',
      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform,
      kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight),
      bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight))
```

Helper functions using tf.keras:

```
def _dense(inputs, units, l2_weight):
  return Dense(units,
      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform,
      kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight),
      bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight))(inputs)

def _batch_norm(inputs, is_training):
  return BatchNormalization(momentum=0.999, epsilon=0.001)(inputs, training = is_training)


def _deconv2d(inputs, filters, kernel_size, stride, l2_weight):
  return Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters, kernel_size=[kernel_size, kernel_size], strides=[stride, stride],
                                      activation=keras.activations.relu, padding='same',
                                      kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform,
                                      kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight),
                                      bias_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight))(inputs)

def _conv2d(inputs, filters, kernel_size, stride, l2_weight):
  return Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=[kernel_size, kernel_size], strides=[stride, stride], padding='same',
      kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform,
      kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight),
      bias_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=l2_weight))(inputs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, tfgan currently relies on variable_scopes in order to work properly and Keras layers don't respect variable_scopes. We have general plans for a redesign that will support Keras, but at the moment we unfortunately don't have anything to show for it or an ETA. Code contributions welcome!